# Proof of Neumann Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices

Consider the theorem

Given 
  that $\lambda_k$ is the $k$th eigenvalue of $A$, the following
  identity holds when $|\lambda_k | < 1$:
$$
(I + A)^{-1} = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^iA^i.
$$

1. Is this theorem true?
2. If yes, then how one can prove it or cite it?

I have used this theorem in a scientific paper but I don't know how to properly cite it.

Comment: Consider the partial sum of the series, and then take limit.

Comment: This is only true if $\max_k |\lambda_k| < 1$. The series is called Neumann Series.